# unresolved external symbol for structures in cpp?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, linker

I know most of time you get UNRESOLVED EXTERNAL SYMBOL for not including library or for not correctly defining function in class, but i get same error for structure.
I have few files .cpp and .h in one of the .h i have defined

```
extern struct MyDataStruct StructData;
```

I include this .h in my .cpp file but i get

```
'struct MyDataStruct StructData' unresolved external symbol
```

I define this structure out of any class and i access it without any class prefix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually define it in one and one only .cpp file ie allocate some space in the object file for it e.g.

```
struct MyDataStruct StructData;
```

Note in this case there is no extern.

Whilst all other code accesses it through the declaration in the header which retains the extern - which tells the compiler and linker that somewhere else in the executable there is something to resolve the reference.

Comment: You do the memory is in one place and all the other .cpp files can access it

Comment: Basically the struct needs to be allocated somewhere, so if you declare it in a single arbitrary .cpp file, any other .cpp file can access it with extern.

Comment: It is a declaration both with and without `extern`.  I think you mean 'You need to actually define it'.